# How do I find the local address on my mac so that I can scp?

Tags: macos, command-line, scp

I am on another computer, but I want to scp some files over to my macbook pro. 
The command for this is:

```
scp -rp filename.txt user@path
```

How do I find the address/path of my mac? I tried

```
ifconfig
```

on my mac and a lot of descriptions popped up, including several numbers that could be IP addresses. However, I don't know how to interpret the data. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of ifconfig gives the different interfaces your computer has. You might find several ip addresses, depending if you have both wired and/or wireless connections and/or other types. 
The interfaces are listed like enX (en1, en2.. etc) depending on the number of interfaces you got.
For ipv4 address, look at the "inet:" part, usually something like 192.x.x.x., 83.x.x.x or something similar.

As an example,

> ifconfig | grep inet

will result in the different inet(ipv4) addresses in your computer, for the different interfaces.

Comment: Of course, but a wild guess from my side was that he/she was interested in the ipv4 address. Looking at for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/14409/how-to-make-scp-to-use-ipv6-addresses, to make use of inet6 you might need to append the -6 flag.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. When you use ifconfig on the far left you'll see a column with items like hi,lo,eth0,eth1,etc... These are the interfaces. Usually, the main interface is going to be eth0. Next to this should be a line which begins with `inet addr:`. The IP after that is your IP address. Use that to connect to that PC.